# blog post edit from MongoDB does not save changes in NodeJS, ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have created a blog site in NodeJS, EJS using mongodb.  My problem is my posts show up from my database but I I want to make a change to it, it won't save.

app.js

```
app.post('/do-edit-post/:postId',(req, res) => {
  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.updateOne({ _id:requestedPostId }, {$set: {
     title: req.body.title,
     author:req.body.author,
     content:req.body.content
  }
  }, function (err, result) {
       if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {
      console.log("Post Updated successfully");
      res.redirect("/admin");
  }
 });
 });
```

In my editpostID.ejs:

```
<form class="" action="/do-edit-post" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label>Title</label>
<input class="form-control" hidden="<%= post._id %>">
 <input class="form-control" text="text" name="postTitle" value="<%= title %>">
 <label>Author</label>
 <input class="form-control" text="text" name="postAuthor" value="<%= author %>">
 <label>Post</label> 
 <!-- Text area matching the selector specified in the TinyMCE configuration -->
 <textarea id="mytextarea" class="form-control" name="postBody" rows="5" cols="30" value=<%- content %>> </textarea>


</div>

<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

I even tried adding a hidden input field of ._id but it's not saving.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add a input name on your hidden input

```
<form class="" action="/do-edit-post" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label>Title</label>
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<%= _id %>" name="postId"> //<-- name added here also you should send the id on input value
 <input class="form-control" text="text" name="postTitle" value="<%= title %>">
 <label>Author</label>
 <input class="form-control" text="text" name="postAuthor" value="<%= author %>">
 <label>Post</label> 
 <!-- Text area matching the selector specified in the TinyMCE configuration -->
 <textarea id="mytextarea" class="form-control" name="postBody" rows="5" cols="30" value=<%- content %>> </textarea>


</div>

<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then on node side you can get the id like this

```
app.post('/do-edit-post/:id',async (req, res) => {
     const requestedPostId = req.body.postId; // <-- get the id from the form 
   
     await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(requestedPostId , {
          title: req.body.title,
          author:req.body.author,
          content:req.body.content
     }).catch(err => {
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            }else{
               console.log("Post Updated successfully");
               res.redirect("/admin");
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got this error on my editPostID.ejs side now when I want to make a change for me editted post.  "post._id is not defined".  Do I need to add it as well on my nodejs side like this: id: req.body._id?

Comment: I tried adding value="<%= _id %>"  in my ejs file but it's still not saving. Can someone please take a look. Also I am confused if I should use this instead updateOne

Comment: The problem is probably on your render also for example you should use this like that <%=post._id> or whatever did you called the rendered data  you should render your data on your update page also you can do with the req.params._id btw your post root should be like this app.post('/do-edit-post/:id')  I ve updated my answer